# How can i update my programs distributively?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, updates, distributed

I have a program that is distributed throughout city. By distributed i mean they are all having same instances and connected to a centralized web api in my office and have two interfaces using two different technologies.
One is ASP MVC  (Web) and another one is WPF.

Assume we have 100 instance of WPF throughout city and there is an update in my web api. How is it possible to update all WPF versions to the latest one? Or how is it possible in ASP MVC version.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you deploy your code to those instances?

Comment: with MVC it is easy enough, since it is installed in a single location (I hope). With WPF it is highly depend on how you deploy your app. If it is MSI - create a patch and distribute it through your web api or by any other means. If it is ClickOnce - simply publish updated version. If it is installed by hands - you have to hurry to run over all 100 instances (sporty way:))

Comment: @mahdi First deployment is physical. I mean i will go there and install it in place. right now i remotely update my apps one by  one

Comment: @vasily.sib For mvc it is installed in a single location.
I have an Exe with its dependencies

Comment: @vasily.sib's recommendation of ClickOnce is the way to go if it is WPF.

Comment: ClickOnce is automatic - it will occur when they launch the app. That is how it works. If you need to do it while it is running, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-check-for-application-updates-programmatically-using-the-clickonce-deployment-api .

Comment: ClickOnce provide means to update-while-running. Our app runs 24/7 too. It asks ClickOnce "Is there any update?" one time per 5 minutes and if "there is" - it silently download and install updated version. Then, user see a message box "App has been updated. Press OK to restart."